# unable to exectute the callback function in MongoClient.connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager'

const client = new MongoClient(url)

client.connect((error,client)=>{
    if(error){
        console.log('unable to connect to database')
    }

    console.log('connected')
})
```

this is my code, and Mongodb is running. when I run 'node app.js' it gets connected to the databse but 'connected' is not printed in the console.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-02T10:55:49.736+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,          "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:51487","uuid":{"uuid":   {"$uuid":"82e75c91-1569-429a-8ab8-f9df73b09bd3"}},"connectionId":8,"connectionCount":8}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-02T10:55:49.739+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn8","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:51487","client":"conn8","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.1.1"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.3.0|2.1.1"},"platform":"Node.js v20.9.0, LE","os":s v20.9.0, LE","os":{"name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621","type":"Windows_NT"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-02T10:58:04.729+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:51502","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"0ff1492e-4251-4162-8f2c-511ecec28105"}},"connectionId":9,"connectionCount":9}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-02T10:58:04.732+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn9","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:51502","client":"conn9","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"6.3.0"},"platform":"Node.js v20.5.0, LE","os":{"name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621","type":"Windows_NT"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-02T10:58:15.244+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:51504","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"94614883-ab8a-45b6-88f6-d1e1eb3fbbcb"}},"connectionId":10,"connectionCount":10}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-02T10:58:15.246+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn10","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:51504","client":"conn10","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"6.3.0"},"platform":"Node.js v20.5.0, LE","os":{"name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621","type":"Windows_NT"}}}}
```

this is the console of mongodb.

I have tried my best to solve the problem. I have even tried to change my firewall settings to identify the problem and have enabled port '27017' in my firewall settings but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Try `await client.connect(...)`.

Comment: Message `'unable to connect to database'` is not a useful error message. You should print the real error

Comment: MongoDB's latest node.js driver doesn't support callbacks: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/v5.0/whats-new/